# Filtering Leaflet Map based on dropdown selection in D3

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I'm trying to filter my map markers layer based on selection of industry in dropdown list of which I've manually referenced in my html here - I'd like to initially retain the pre-loaded marker data and provide an option to filter the markers by selection from the dropdown.

```
<select class="dropdown" id="selDataset">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Industry</option>
              <option value ="ind1">Accomodation and Food Services</option>
              <option value ="ind2">Educational Services</option>
              <option value ="ind3">Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services</option>
              <option value ="ind4">Professional, Scientific, and Technical Services</option>
              <option value ="ind5">Manufacturing</option>
              <option value ="ind6">Construction</option>
              <option value ="ind7">Health Care and Social Assistance</option>
              <option value ="ind8">Wholesale Trade</option>
              <option value ="ind9">Information</option>
     </select>
```

Here is my .js code - My guess is I need to define a function that encloses the first for loop and setting an if else statement if a selection is made to filter lat,lng for that industry, else return all by default. I'm just not sure how to reference the html dropdown selection to filter the markers. I have implemented drop downs via D3.js for table filtering, and have used overlay layers before, but I can't find an implementation of this using leaflet marker layers.

```js
// Creating map object
var myMap = L.map("map", {
  center: [40.73, -74.0059],
  zoom: 11
});

// Adding tile layer to the map
L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(myMap);

var data = [{
    lat: 40.75,
    lng: -73.99,
    BusinessName: 'Bank LLC',
    Industry: 'Banking'
  },
  {
    lat: 40.73,
    lng: -73.97,
    BusinessName: 'Some Hotel',
    Industry: 'Hospitality'
  },
  {
    lat: 40.74,
    lng: -74.00,
    BusinessName: 'Other Hotel',
    Industry: 'Hospitality'
  }
];

// Create a new marker cluster group
var markers = L.layerGroup();

// Loop through data
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // Set the latitude, longitude property to a variable
  var latitude = data[i].lat;
  var longitude = data[i].lng;
  var popText = ("<h3>" + data[i].BusinessName + "</h3><h3>Industry: " + data[i].Industry + "</h3>");
  // var industry = data[i].Industry;
  // var mySelector = $("#Industry").val();
  // Check for location property

  if (latitude) {
    // Add a new marker to the cluster group and bind a pop-up
    markers.addLayer(L.marker([latitude, longitude])
      .bindPopup(popText));
  };
}
// Add our marker cluster layer to the map
myMap.addLayer(markers);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you could create a [mre] of your code, preferably in a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) with some sample/dummy data that helps us understand the problem. That way, we can more easily answer your question and you'll be more likely to get a good answer!

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Hi Ruben, thank you for the reply. I'm not 100% sure on how to supplement for data within my js script to provide a running code snippet  without significantly altering my .js file to account for data read-in without referencing source file which I believe is integral to sought solution. However, I do have a running heroku app that could suffice.

Comment: Could you provide a few rows of sample data from the CSV file? They can have dummy values, it's just about the structure.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot https://ibb.co/m5SKxZq

Answer (score 1):

The way D3 works is not by redrawing everything from scratch, but by updating the underlying data that the selection works with:

1. Have a function `draw()` that draws the given data. Inside `draw()`, make sure you also remove any remnants of the old drawings;
2. Use D3 to set the correct options in the dropdown (better than hardcoded, because definitions might change in the future);
3. Whenever the dropdown value changes, call `draw` with a subset of the underlying data;
4. Call `draw()` with all data to provide initial markers.

For your code, have a look at array functions, like [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), as they're generally very useful when working with data like this.

```js
// Creating map object
var myMap = L.map("map", {
  center: [40.73, -74.0059],
  zoom: 11
});

// Adding tile layer to the map
L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(myMap);

var allData = [{
    lat: 40.75,
    lng: -73.99,
    BusinessName: 'Bank LLC',
    Industry: 'Banking'
  },
  {
    lat: 40.73,
    lng: -73.97,
    BusinessName: 'Some Hotel',
    Industry: 'Hospitality'
  },
  {
    lat: 40.74,
    lng: -74.00,
    BusinessName: 'Other Hotel',
    Industry: 'Hospitality'
  }
];

// Create a new marker cluster group
var markers = L.layerGroup();
// Add our marker cluster layer to the map
myMap.addLayer(markers);

function draw(data) {
  // Start fresh
  markers.clearLayers();

  // Loop through data
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Set the latitude, longitude property to a variable
    var latitude = data[i].lat;
    var longitude = data[i].lng;
    var popText = ("<h3>" + data[i].BusinessName + "</h3><h3>Industry: " + data[i].Industry + "</h3>");
    // var industry = data[i].Industry;
    // var mySelector = $("#Industry").val();
    // Check for location property

    if (latitude) {
      // Add a new marker to the cluster group and bind a pop-up
      markers.addLayer(L.marker([latitude, longitude])
        .bindPopup(popText));
    };
  }
}

var industries = allData
  .map(function(row) {
    return row.Industry;
  })
  .sort()
  .filter(function(v, i, arr) {
    // This selects only unique industries:
    // Only return a value if it's the first occurrence or if
    // it's different from the previous entry in the sorted(!) array
    return i === 0 || arr[i - 1] != v;
  });

draw(allData);

d3.select("#selectIndustries")
  // Select all non-disabled options
  // to avoid touching the placeholder one
  .selectAll("option:not([disabled])")
  .data(industries)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

d3.select("#selectIndustries")
  .on("change", function() {
    var selection = this.value;
    var filteredData = allData.filter(function(d) {
      return d.Industry == selection;
    });
    draw(filteredData);
  });
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<select id="selectIndustries">
  <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
</select>
```